# Compare text and nodes after a certain node

Tags: xslt-2.0

I try to figure out how to address a certain part of a closer-statement of a letter. In this xml-file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
    <closer>regards<lb/><signed>William</signed></closer>
    <closer>until next tuesday<lb/>regards<lb/><signed>William</signed></closer>
    <closer>until next tuesday<lb/>regards <signed>William</signed></closer>
</a>
```

I am positioned at the last linebreak (lb) and want to know whether there is more text following than just the signature. I fruitlessly tried things like

```
//substring-after(parent::closer, lb[last()]) = signed
```

But it did not work. How do I properly test for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `following-sibling::node()[not(self::signed)]` to select any nodes following the context node (which you say is an `lb` element) that are not `signed` elements. In a boolean context like `<xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()[not(self::signed)]">` that would then evaluate to true only if such a node exists.